# How do i say bye bye to looking like steve on minecraft pc

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On mine craft i'm tired of looking Steve. How do i change this

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate. The question linked is not specifically asking _how_ to change the skin but rather if you can on singleplayer. The only two positive answers don't mention going to minecraft.net and doing that sort. With some editing of this question, this is a perfectly fine in my opinion.

Comment: @aman207 MBraedley's answer covers going to minecraft.net, I recommend upvoting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to [minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/) and Log In if you have an account, from there you can upload a skin to your profile. There are various Minecraft skin sites that you can download from, including several programs you can download to make your own.

Comment: Thanks for being the first to speak it helped alot :D cant wait to show my freinds my herobrines bride skin :D.

Comment: I made a slender man skin for my friend XD

Comment: awesome that is really cool

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a premium account, you can head over to the Minecraft website and change it there by following a few easy steps.

1. Download a skin
2. Open [the profile page on the Minecraft website](https://minecraft.net/profile) and login.
3. Browse for the skin and click upload

Your new skin will be applied almost instantly. If you had Minecraft open,  restart your client to update your skin.